# Node Express - Getting a Cannot GET or request returning html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a backend api with node/express and am running into an error. I've tried many different approaches as well as looked at many different questions on here, but none seem to fix my problem. As far as I can tell my routes are structured properly, but they simply don't work. Perhaps I'm missing something super obvious, but I'm at a loss.

Bellow is a simplified version of my index.js where I start my node server:

```
const movies = require("./routes/movies");

app.use("/api/movies/", movies);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

And then in my movies.js I have several endpoints:

```
// DOES WORK - returns movies with the specifed object
router.get("/genre/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const movies = await Movie.find({ genres: req.params.id });

  if (!movies)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(`No movies with genre of id ${req.params.id} could be found.`);

  res.send(movies);
});

// DOESN'T WORK - returns main html page
router.get("/tmdbid/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const movie = await Movie.findOne({
    tmdbID: req.params.id,
  });

  if (!movie)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(`No movies with tmdbID of ${req.params.id} could be found.`);

  if (res.status(404)) res.send("Route not found");

  res.send(movie);
});

// DOESN'T WORK - returns Cannot GET /api/movies/title/{title}
router.get("/title/:title", async (req, res) => {
    const movie = await Movie.find({
    title: { $regex: new RegExp(req.params.title, "i")
},});

if (!movie)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send(`The movie with name of ${req.params.title} could not be found.`);

    res.send(movie);
});
```

I'm not sure what needs to be done here. All of these share similar syntax, but each result in a different response. None of them log any errors to the terminal either. I know for sure general refactoring should be done, but as far as the problem at hand goes, I can't wrap my head around why the last two aren't working. Lastly, I have several other endpoints in the this file, all of which are working fine. Just these two have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found my answer and it was simply a mistake I had in the url when calling the endpoint, not in the endpoint's code itself. Rather than calling to localhost:5000, I was calling to localhost:3000, which is probably why it was returning the index.html of my react app.

So, my code works as is. Perhaps not the best structure ever, but as long as it works, I'm happy.

Still not sure why the /title/:title endpoint wasn't working and then suddenly was. That remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Add a console.log statement to check whether the endpoint is hit or not. The code logic in your code sample above sounds right. However, I would try formatting the code batter.

```
 if (!movie){
return res.status(400).send(`No movies with genre of id ${req.params.id} could be found.`);
}
```

Also, make sure you do not forget to restart your node js server.

Comment: Well the /title/:title endpoint randomly started working. I hadn't even changed anything. The /tmdb/:id endpoint console.log is not being ran though. This is the endpoint that returns the index.html for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

What are those `return` statements doing there? and you could improve your if statements as well like such ->

```
try {
  const movie = await Movie.findOne({
    tmdbID: req.params.id,
  });
  if (!movie) {
   res
   .status(400)
   .send(`No movie(s) could be found.`);
  } else {
    res
    .status(200)
    .send(movie);
  }
} catch(err) {
  res.send(500);
}
```